# docker container does not work after restart

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have a VM and inside it, I am running an Elasticsearch Docker container built through `docker-compose`. It was working pretty well. Then after the power suddenly went out, I tried running the container back again but discovered an error that wasn't present before:

[image]

Then the container kept on restarting. And when I checked the file permissions (within the small window of time before the container restarts), I found this:

[image]

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.3'
services:       
elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.0
    hostname: elasticsearch
    restart: always
    user: root
    ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"
    volumes:
       - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    env_file:
        - devopsfw-elk.env
```

What is actually happening here? I'm fairly new to Docker and Elasticsearch and I'm very confused as to the errors that are occuring.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the file has been corrupted, delete it and restart the container.

```
rm -i ./*elasticsearch.yml*
```

If you have problems to delete this, read this:
https://superuser.com/questions/197605/delete-a-corrupt-file-in-linux

Comment: it doesn't work at all, its says 'Permission denied'

Comment: Are you entering the container with the correct user? Like this: docker exec -u elasticsearch

Comment: i'm entering as the root user

Comment: You could try to recreate the file with the following command: touch elasticsearch.yml

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done, since I can docker exec into it for max 3 seconds before it closes due to errors

Comment: You have the container up at the same time that you execute in other terminal the exec sentence? Edit your post and post the errors please.

Comment: The errors above are the only errors I have, I have no other errors. I start the container then run `docker exec -it elasticsearch_con /bin/bash`, which can let me enter at max 3 seconds then shoves me out due to the errors above

Comment: Ok, you try edit your docker-compose and edit volume line : - ./elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch2.yml , Maybe this allows you to enter and you can keep the session open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221326/discussion-between-alfro93-and-lee-m).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file was owned by the root user and has been corrupted, in order to delete the file, you have to use the super user access aka `sudo` , so correct command would be

```
sudo  rm -i ./*elasticsearch.yml*
```

And after that, create a file and restart the conatainer.

Comment: tried it with sudo, error is: bash: sudo: command not found

Comment: but it exits within 3 seconds, also i'm using centOS, but still it closes immediately

Comment: None actually, it just closes on its own, probably because I set it to restart=always. I can like docker exec into for max 3 seconds